# integration firebase messaging with mac os apps ? (Notifications)

Tags: swift, firebase, macos, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

guys maybe somone is doing integration firebase messaging with mac os apps (Notifications)? I tried to search in Google and found nothing. Can anyone come across such a problem can suggest or give some source?

Answer (score 5):

**Update**: Firebase Cloud Messaging nowadays also can deliver messages to other Apple platforms such as macOS and tvOS. Also see issue [#11964](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/11964) on the GitHub repo of the Firebase iOS+ SDK.

For what specific Apple platforms are supported, see [Firebase library support by platform](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/learn-more#firebase_library_support_by_platform) in the documentation.

Comment: [screen link](https://ibb.co/4dD3rMx)
When im created apps for ios/ipados actiualy its work fine, and after im select the “mac”, and then in the mac version notifications with FCM working fine too. Maybe did u know some solution for that ?

Comment: I have no idea what I'm looking at in that link. Can you edit your question to both include the image with the ads, and to clarify?

Comment: 2023 Update: FCM is supported for macOS. More discussion at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/11964