# How to subscribe to events over http in firebase messaging service?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

As far as I understand for different mobile devices, firebase messaging service uses different protocols like web push, ans, google play services. But is there a way to notify non mobile device using this service?

Comment: Is this what your are looking for: https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging

Comment: I'm looking how can I subscribe to event over HTTP with firebase cloud messaging service

Answer (score 1):

Delivery of messages over Firebase Cloud Messaging is only supported to the SDKs listed in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), currently iOS, Android and Web. There is no documentation for the wire protocol that is used to deliver messages to these clients.

Also see these previous questions asking for delivery to Windows, macOS, and Linux:

- [How to receive push notifications from Firebase cloud messaging on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507588/how-to-receive-push-notifications-from-firebase-cloud-messaging)
- [Is it possible to develop flutter windows desktop with fcm push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71555612/is-it-possible-to-develop-flutter-windows-desktop-with-fcm-push-notification)
- [integration firebase messaging with mac os apps ? (Notifications)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68626936/integration-firebase-messaging-with-mac-os-apps-notifications)
- [Can we use FireBase cloud Messaging to send or receive messages or both ways using C++ on Windows Desktop/Console or Linux console appliction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229503/can-we-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-to-send-or-receive-messages-or-both-ways-usi)